# Seemingly simple high school combinatorics proof doesn't add up

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Prove that $\binom{n}{n-2}\binom{n+2}{n-1}$ is an integer for all $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.

My take on this:

Recall: $${n\choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

So our problem reads (simplified): $$\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!} \cdot \frac{(n+2)!}{(n-1)3!}$$

But simply substituting $n=1$ does not work for the problem (answer becomes $-\frac{1}{2}$) and therefore the original assumption must be wrong? Or am I misunderstanding?

I'm stuck in the proof:

Trying to multiply these fractions together I can get:

$$\frac{n!(n+2)!}{12(n-2)!(n-1)!}$$ and I can divide $n!$ by $(n-1)!$ to get $$\frac{n(n+2)!}{12(n-2)!}$$ but I'm stuck here. This still does not clearly show that the answer is an integer.

Comment: Don't you mean $n\geq 2$?

Comment: My professor does not. It clearly states n larger or equal to 1.

Comment: For $n=1$ you get $0$, no? $\binom{1}{-1}=0$.

Comment: for $n=1$, it doesn't work at all; factorial is undefined for negative numbers like $(1-2)=-1$

Comment: Also, I find this to be a weird problem. Either binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ are known to be integers, which solves your problem immediately, and otherwise this is not known, in which case it would make more sense to prove that the general expression $\binom{n}{k}$ is integer.

Comment: @Dan: The factorial is undefined, but the binomial coefficient is defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition $\dbinom{n}k=0$ when $k<0$, so

$$\binom{1}{-1}\binom{3}0=0\cdot1=0\;.$$

**Added:** In the edited question you’ve reduced the case $n\ge 2$ to showing that

$$\frac{n(n+2)!}{12(n-2)!}$$

is an integer. Do a bit more cancellation to get

$$\frac{n^2(n+2)(n+1)(n-1)}{12}\;.$$

Now show that any product of four consecutive integers is a multiple of $12$.

Comment: How come it doesn't work when I lay it out in the combinatoric formula then?

Comment: @Paze: Because the formula with the factorials applies only when $k\ge 0$. The case $k<0$ requires a separate definition.

Comment: So it is essentially impossible to prove for n=1? It is simply correct by definition?

Comment: @Paze: You prove it by applying the definition of $\binom{n}k$. For $n\ge 2$ this is the factorial computation that you were making; for $n=1$ it’s the computation that I made.

Comment: I see. I did not know this definition, though.

However my proof is incomplete and I'm stuck with it, could you give me a hand?

I've edited my question to show you where I'm at.

Comment: @Paze: I’ve added a hint; see if you can take it from there.